# How to echo Hyperlink Containing a Variable?

Tags: php, string-formatting

In the code below, I would like to make the word that prints out as the variable "$submittor" a hyperlink to `"http://www...com/.../members/index.php?profile=$submittor"` .

I can't get it to work; I think I'm doing the formatting wrong.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
echo '<div class="sitename3name">Submitted by '.$submittor.' on '.$dt->format('F j, Y &\nb\sp &\nb\sp g:i a').'</div>';
```

Comment: Is `$submittor` set to anything? Can you show us what is being printed?

Comment: It's a variable that echoes out correctly as is.

Answer (score 1):

You've left out the link.

```
$link="<a href='http://www...com/.../members/index.php?profile=$submittor>$submittor</a>";
echo '<div class="sitename3name">Submitted by '.$link.' on '.$dt->format('F j, Y &\nb\sp &\nb\sp g:i a').'</div>';
```

Comment: I think @John wanted the link to be a link to the profile page of `$submittor`. So you'd need something like `$link="<a href='http://example.com/index.php?profile=$submittor'>$submittor</a>"`

Comment: @psmears: I think you caught me in the editing cycle. His URL had just shown up and I was fixing my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Hmmm.... this looked promising, but when I added it, it made some of the other code (that is not included in this question) not print.

Comment: Fair enough :) @John: You'll have to give more details. The code posted by dnagirl is correct - perhaps you could post *all* of the code you're having trouble with? And the result of "View Source" in the browser so we can see what the result is?